# If the Apple Watch has wifi - does it connect to my local router?

Tags: network, wifi, router, apple-watch

It would appear the Apple Watch has the ability to communicate [via wifi](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/04/09/apple-watch-limited-functions-iphone/).

When I set mine up, I didn't have a step to identify my local router, so I assume it may have obtained configuration about my local router from my phone, or that it doesn't connect (directly) to my router at all.

My question is: **If the Apple Watch has wifi - does it connect to my local router?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It uses the wifi networks already configured on your phone. Mine worked over my home network perfectly with zero configuration on my part.